# How to write overloaded generic extension methods for T[], T[][] without ambiguity?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, default-parameters

I want to write extension methods for converting a vector and matrix into string. I did this in the following way.

**For Vector**

```
public static string GetString<T>(this T[] SourceMatrix, string ColumnDelimiter = " ")
{
    try
    {
        string result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < SourceMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            result += SourceMatrix[i] + ColumnDelimiter;
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ee) { return null; }
}
```

**For Matrix**

```
public static string GetString<T>(this T[][] SourceMatrix, string ColumnDelimiter = " ", string RowDelimiter = "\n")
{
    try
    {
        string result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < SourceMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < SourceMatrix[i].GetLength(0); j++)
                result += SourceMatrix[i][j] + "" + ColumnDelimiter;
            result += "" + RowDelimiter;
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ee) { return null; }
}
```

Now i am using following code which causes ambiguity.

```
List<double[]> Patterns= GetPatterns(); 
Patterns.ToArray().GetString();
```

**Error**

```
Error   5   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
'MatrixMathLib.MatrixMath.GetString<double[]>(double[][], string)' and 
'MatrixMathLib.MatrixMath.GetString<double>(double[][], string, string)'
```

Can anyone suggest me to write these extension methods correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just a small suggestion, the is already the static string method (`string.Join(<delimiter>,<array>)`) to convert an array to string

Comment: Storing a matrix in a jagged array is odd... Why not use a multi-dimensional one?

Comment: @BadikAli `String.Join` is not a extension method, it is a static method of `string` class.

Comment: @leppie as i mentioned in the code actually i am using `List<double[]>` and using `ToArray()` extension which will return `double[][]`, any way in my problem i need jagged array as each row(pattern) can have different no.of values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your methods. It is the compiler that can't choose between them.

As you can see in the error message, the compiler could assume `T` to be `double[]` and match the first method, or `double` and match the second one. This will be solved by explicitly mentioning which method you want to use:

```
Patterns.ToArray().GetString<double>();
```

Comment: perhaps a little late?

Comment: Come on Mitch. there is no rep for a late answer, so it's just a good deed!

Comment: @MitchWheat: (Edit: This was to your now-deleted comment.) Uhm, actually, unlike you, he actually *answered* the question when he said the compiler ***can't*** distinguish between them. You just answered an entirely different question without ever stating whether or not the task as requested was even possible, leaving the OP hanging in midair. +1 for Alireza.

Comment: @MitchWheat: Maybe you should start giving it a little more then.

Comment: @MitchWheat Will it help if I delete my answer? A few reps are not worth it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can either omit the default values or state the type of T in the function call

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't tell whether you want to call `GetString<double[]>` or `GetString<double>` because both methods fit the invocation.

The easiest way to solve that is to simply change one of the names (i.e. `GetArrayString<T>`). A better solution IMO is to have only 1 method that solves both cases like this one:

```
public static string Join<T>(this T[] sourceMatrix, string columnDelimiter = " ", string rowDelimiter = "\n")
{
    if (sourceMatrix.Length == 0)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    if (sourceMatrix[0] as Array == null)
    {
        return string.Join(columnDelimiter, sourceMatrix);
    }

    var rows = new List<string>();
    foreach (T item in sourceMatrix)
    {
        var array = item as Array;
        var row = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(0); j++)
            row += array.GetValue(j) + columnDelimiter;
        rows.Add(row);
    }

    return string.Join(rowDelimiter, rows);
}
```

Usage:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
int[] b = { 1, 2, 4 };
int[][] c = {a, b};

Console.WriteLine(a.Join());
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(c.Join());
```

Output:

```
1 2 3

1 2 3
1 2 4
```

---

Note: This only solves for 1-2 dimensions, but can easily be generalized to n dimensions.